# Prove that if $A$ is independent of $B$, $A$ is independent of $C$, then $A$ is independent of $B\cup C$.

Tags: probability

Prove that if $A$ is independent of $B$, $A$ is independent of $C$, then $A$ is independent of $B\cup C$.

$\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(AB)$

$\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{P}(AC)$

So what we seek to prove is $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B\cup C)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap (B\cup C))$

Basically I got it to

$\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B\cup C)=\mathbb{P}(AB)+\mathbb{P}(AC)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(BC)$

$\mathbb{P}(A\cap (B\cup C))=\mathbb{P}(AB)+\mathbb{P}(AC)-\mathbb{P}(AB \cap AC)$

But i don't know how to prove $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(BC)=\mathbb{P}(AB \cap AC)$

Any one can help me out...?

Furthermore, if we add in the constrain $B\cap C=\emptyset$ how would that influence the result. It looks like it won't imo.

Comment: "Prove that if $A$ is independent of $B$, $A$ is independent of $C$, then $A$ is independent of $B\cup C$." Difficult, very difficult, since the result is actually false (and you were probably NOT asked to prove it).

Comment: The $B \cap C = \emptyset$ seem to change everything since I think that would make an otherwise false statement true.

Comment: @Did god-.- they question just said prove the statement so i assumed it was correct.. cracked my brain to prove a false statement true. thanks a lot man!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove something that is not true.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pairwise_independent.svg)  there is pairwise independence (so even $B$ and $C$ are independent) but:

$$P\left(A\cap\left(B\cup C\right)\right)=\frac{11}{40}\neq\frac{1}{2}\frac{5}{8}=P\left(A\right)P\left(B\cup C\right)$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the terms "pairwise independence", "mutual independence" and "independence". i read the definitions but i still don't get what it means and what repercussions it would have. (However, i do roughly know how to prove them mathematically)

Just to confirm. does $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(AB)$ signify independence or mutual independence.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events) to inform yourself properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another example where your claim doesn't hold:

Toss three fair coins, starting over until an odd number of them show heads, and let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be the events where the first, second or third coin shows heads, respectively. Then the events are pairwise independent, but $A$ is not independent of $B\cup C$.

(In more computery language: randomly uniformly choose three bits such that their XOR is $1$.)

Comment: A slightly easier formulation: Toss two coins and define the third coin to be the XOR of the first two coins.

Comment: @Dominik: Yes, it's slightly easier (+1), but it also makes the symmetry less apparent.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is wrong, as can be seen from the following example:

[image]